# Custom fonts aren't working

Tags: objective-c, ios, fonts

That we can use a custom font within my app is not a secret, but I can't reach this and wonder why.

Of course I searched the whole web for this problem but nowhere found something similar, so this is why I finally need to ask this.

What I'm trying: I'm on my way to create a small game and draw always my whole gamefield. Good, this works just fine with the default fonts, but doesn't with my custom font...

I added my .ttf-Font (I tried two different) to my project using drag and drop and copy it to my project folder. Next I added `MyFontXY.ttf` to my `Info.plist` using UIAppFonts and an array.

Next I tried to use it with `[UIFont fontWithName:@"MyFontXY.ttf" size:12]` - ok fine, doesn't work. I searched for the real name of the font and tried `[UIFont fontWithName:@"My Font XY" size12]` but it doesn't work, too.

So I tried several things after this like cleaning, reimport, change the name, ... but nothing happened. I also used `NSLog(@"%@",[UIFont fontFamilies])` to find out which fonts are available, but my font wasn't there.

I also checked if the numbers were available with this font and they are, so I excluded a lot of possibilities now.

What can I do now? Does someone has this problem too?

Comment: Did you add the ttf file to your target?

Comment: I needed to add them manual to "Copy Bundle Resources". I'll go away and shame. Please create an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: You are welcome, sometimes we mis the obvious, we are only human ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to add the fonts to your target, for instance by manually adding them in the "Copy Bundle Resources" phase of your target